# REACT: WEBPACK: Build to PROD showing local machine path in SourceMap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, progressive-web-apps

This is probably a very stupid question but I'm not a REACT developer and I've never worked with it before. So, I had to deploy a React build in my cloud server and I found out after making it work, that the browser's console shows my machine paths.

Can anyone point me out in the right direction here?
[image: ,]

Here's the code for my webpack.config.prod.js:

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
const publicPath = paths.servedPath;
// Some apps do not use client-side routing with pushState.
// For these, "homepage" can be set to "." to enable relative asset paths.
const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';
// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = false;//process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
const publicUrl = publicPath.slice(0, -1);
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// Assert this just to be safe.
// Development builds of React are slow and not intended for production.
if (env.stringified['process.env'].NODE_ENV !== '"production"') {
  throw new Error('Production builds must have NODE_ENV=production.');
}

// Note: defined here because it will be used more than once.
const cssFilename = 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css';

// ExtractTextPlugin expects the build output to be flat.
// (See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/27)
// However, our output is structured with css, js and media folders.
// To have this structure working with relative paths, we have to use custom options.
const extractTextPluginOptions = shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths
  ? // Making sure that the publicPath goes back to to build folder.
    { publicPath: Array(cssFilename.split('/').length).join('../') }
  : {};

// This is the production configuration.
// It compiles slowly and is focused on producing a fast and minimal bundle.
// The development configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  // Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
  bail: true,
  // We generate sourcemaps in production. This is slow but gives good results.
  // You can exclude the *.map files from the build during deployment.
  devtool: shouldUseSourceMap ? 'source-map' : false,
  // In production, we only want to load the polyfills and the app code.
  entry: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],
  output: {
    // The build folder.
    path: paths.appBuild,
    // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
    // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
    // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
    // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path
        .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
        .replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
   // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {

      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // TODO: Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      // We are waiting for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2176.
      // { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.


      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader'] },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]' },
      {
        test: /(\.sass)$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader?sourceMap']
      },
      {
        test: /(\.css)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /(\.scss)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
        ]
      },

      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
    // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV was set to production here.
    // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // Minify the code.
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2376
        // Pending further investigation:
        // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
        comparisons: false,
      },
      mangle: {
        safari10: true,
     },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2488
        ascii_only: true,
      },
      sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
    }),
    // Note: this won't work without ExtractTextPlugin.extract(..) in `loaders`.
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: cssFilename,
    }),
    // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
    // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
    // having to parse `index.html`.
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
    }),
    // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
    // the HTML & assets that are part of the Webpack build.
    new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
      // By default, a cache-busting query parameter is appended to requests
      // used to populate the caches, to ensure the responses are fresh.
      // If a URL is already hashed by Webpack, then there is no concern
      // about it being stale, and the cache-busting can be skipped.
      dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /\.\w{8}\./,
      filename: 'service-worker.js',
      logger(message) {
        if (message.indexOf('Total precache size is') === 0) {
          // This message occurs for every build and is a bit too noisy.
          return;
        }
        if (message.indexOf('Skipping static resource') === 0) {
          // This message obscures real errors so we ignore it.
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2612
          return;
        }
        console.log(message);
      },
      minify: true,
      // For unknown URLs, fallback to the index page
      navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
      // Ignores URLs starting from /__ (useful for Firebase):
      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2237#issuecomment-302693219
      navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/__).*/],
      // Don't precache sourcemaps (they're large) and build asset manifest:
      staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
    }),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
};
```

Comment: Looks like you are including the source maps in your deployment. However you are building your application, you should exclude source map generation for production.

Comment: Hi @sdgluck, thanks for your reply... I tried what you said by setting the shouldUseSourceMap constant in the webpack.config.prod.js to false, and then building again. No .map file was generated but still when I look in the browser console I still see my local paths. Can you please lmk if I have to change anything else. Apparently, the main.js file also contains my paths :(

Comment: Depends how you're building your app but you haven't shown any code. I would say it isn't a big concern unless the source map file is embedded in the same file with the rest of the source, as your js shouldn't have sensitive code in it anyway

Comment: @Dominic you're right, the sourcemap seems now to be embedded in the main js file. How do I remove it? I haven't shown any code because basically I wouldn't know what part of it actually matters for this issue.

Comment: @met.lord The relevant part will be in your webpack config best to just post that and also what version you're using

Comment: @Dominic would you mind taking a look? I just added the webpack.config file. I did set const shouldUseSourceMap = false; but it doesn't seem to have the behavior I'd expect. Thanks!

Comment: You can see there is says `// We generate sourcemaps in production. This is slow but gives good results.
  // You can exclude the *.map files from the build during deployment.
  devtool: shouldUseSourceMap ? 'source-map' : false,`

Comment: So it sounds like it's generated as a separate map file, have you check your build folder? `paths.appBuild`

Comment: @Dominic it was generating a sourcemap, so it set shouldUseSourceMap = false and when the code you mention is executed it's false. However, now the map is like you said before, embedded in the main.*.js file after the build is done.

Comment: I wouldn't personally worry if it's generated a separate map file as it's useful for debugging prod and not affecting the client by them having to download extra JS. This also looks like an overly complex build config, any reason for that? Have you considered starting simple or using react-create-app? It also looks like webpack v3 to me.

Comment: @Dominic it worries me because the complete path on my local machine, including my username is there, otherwise I wouldn't care. It's just static content. I'm not sure about why the file is so complex but I'm just the guy deploying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got rid of my problem by setting *sourceMap: false* in the code below:

```
{
        test: /(\.css)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader', options: { sourceMap: false} },
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: false} },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: false} },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: false} }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /(\.scss)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader', options: { sourceMap: false} },
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: false} },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: false} },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: false} }
        ]
      },
```